# Git Submodule to a subfolder

Tags: git, dvcs, git-submodules

In svn you can link a repository to any folder in another svn repository.  I'm wondering if there is a similar feature for git?  Basically I want a git submodule inside my repository, but I want the submodule to be a pointer to a subfolder of another git repository, not the whole repository.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Git does not support partial checkouts, so the [submodule](https://schacon.github.com/git/git-submodule.html) must point to a complete repository.

[This thread on the Git mail list](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/10/15/344049) provides some background information.

[This article from Panther Software](https://web.archive.org/web/20090207160050/http://panthersoftware.com/articles/view/3/svn-s-svn-externals-to-git-s-submodule-for-rails-plugins) offers some insight from someone else trying to accomplish a similar goal (i.e. replicate `svn:externals` using Git).

If both projects are under your control, then I suggest you isolate the "subfolder" that you interested in to its own standalone repo.  Then both projects can create submodules that link to it.

Comment: Yes, it does sound like the subfolder should be it's own module if it is to be shared between two projects.

Comment: Link died at Panther Software http://panthersoftware.com/articles/view/3/svn-s-svn-externals-to-git-s-submodule-for-rails-plugins

Answer (score 24):

I'm running into the same issue. It doesn't look solvable from a git level, at least not in a way that lets you easily pull or push to the parent repo.

However, you can work around this limitation by using a simple symlink:

1. Set up your submodule in a separate directory.

   - `git submodule add http://example.com/repo.git ./submodules/repo`
2. Create a symlink to the subfolder in the place you want:

   - `ln -s ./submodules/repo/subdirectory ./wherever/symlinked_directory`

---

References:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/

Comment: for windows users, try `mklink`

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you're trying to extract a subfolder of some other project, that subfolder should be a separate project in the first place, and *both* parent projects should be referring to it.

You can extract such a subproject's history using a tool like [git subtree](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree).  Then you can link the subtree back into your project using either git submodule or git subtree, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Not always.  For example I want to pull Twitter Bootstrap into my project to use the .less files.  I don't need all the examples and parser, etc.  just the .less files from the /lib/ folder.  Currently I cannot get that on it's own using a submodule

Comment: You can map just a specific subdirectory to a directory in your repo using `git subtree`.