# Git submodule from just a directory of another repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to create a submodule that does not link to a repository directly, but to a directory inside it?

For example, let fw.git be a framework repository, with these dirs:

```
|fw.git
\---|test
    |code
    |tools
```

I'd like to submodule the framework code, just the `code` directory, not other directories.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121227/git-submodule-to-a-subfolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Linus intentionally made git not work like that.