# How to load files dynamically on launch with docker?

Tags: python, docker

I’m working on a project that will need to load python code files dynamically from GitHub on launch. Here’s what it needs to look like:

1. User asks us to launch an instance for them and provides us with a GitHub url
2. We have an existing docker with our own python code (a server) that will be using those files from GitHub
3. We need to launch the docker with our own code, but subbing in parts that we got from the users GitHub, basically creating a server with half our code, half user code

In other words, we need to launch a docker that has some pre planned code from us, and some dynamic code from the user.

Any ideas how to do this? I’ve seen many examples of docker files that load code from GitHub, but I’m having a hard time figuring out how to make it half our code, and half code dynamically from GitHub on run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the git submodule command to import a subset of another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293902/can-i-use-the-git-submodule-command-to-import-a-subset-of-another-repository)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino no I don’t think it does because our code is not public and cannot be included as a sub module by the users. It may be possible for us to do the reverse, but then we would have to create a different hit repo for every single set of client code, which will become very messy