# How to change a git submodule to point to a subfolder?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Skimming through [the SubModule tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial), I created a submodule out of the [boto project](https://github.com/boto/boto). Then, I discovered that I actually need only a subset of this project - specifically, the [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/master/boto) folder.

I would like to change my submodule to point to this folder. When I look in .gitmodules, I see

```
[submodule "backup/src/boto"]
    path = backup/src/boto
    url = https://github.com/boto/boto.git
```

What URL should I use instead of https://github.com/boto/boto.git? After I change the URL, should I delete the boto folder locally and re-pull?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want - not a submodule - but you might have a look at [`git subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)

Comment: What I ended up doing is having the entire submodule, and telling IntelliJ that the boto folder is a 'source folder', so it can find packages in it.

Comment: I can't believe git doesn't do this natively...yikes.

Comment: Found a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121227/git-submodule-to-a-subfolder

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I'm afraid the URL for submodules always just points to the repository - you can't specify that you only want a subfolder of a repository, in the same way that git doesn't support "narrow clones" in general.

If you can't live with having the whole repository as a submodule, you could always create a new repository that's cloned from boto and then set up a cron job to:

1. `git fetch` that repository into a directory
2. Use `git filter-branch` to update a branch where the subdirectory is at the top level.
3. Add that branch of the repository as the submodule.  However, that's all a bit fiddly and my preference would just be to live with having the whole repository as a submodule.

Answer (score 35):

You cannot clone only a part of a repository. This is because git treats the repository as a whole object : when you get it, you get it **all**.

So, the solution here would be to fetch the submodule in another directory, then use a symlink to achieve your goal.

Comment: I have symlinks in windows... works well too.
(that's because of msys I've on my machine, so I can use `ln -s` like in linux)

Comment: Vista and & come with MKLink. I use that. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/

Comment: You can use hard links instead

Comment: @KindDragon: You can't hard link directories

Answer (score 25):

All the answers here are pretty dated. You could use the newer `git sparse-checkout` command [docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout), further examples in [this article](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/) to grab pieces of a repo. This is effective if you only want a directory or two from a larger git project.

TLDR:

```sh
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set <dir1> <dir2> ...
git checkout main
```

Comment: That seems fine if the files are you in YOUR (mono) repo, but what about when the files you want are a subset of a different mono repo - aka a subfolder of a submodule?

Comment: The article says, `if you ran git sparse-checkout set A/B, then Git would include files with names A/B/C.txt (immediate child of A/B) and A/D.txt (immediate sibling of A/B) as well as E.txt (immediate sibling of A).` Personally, I consider this limiting: I only want `A/B/C.txt`. In the context of the question, here's my take: "`sparse-checkout` lets you exclude *root subdirs* from *your repo*. `submodule` lets you include the root of *another repo* anywhere in your repo."

Answer (score 18):

What you want to do is create a branch in the submodule and move the folder up and delete what you don't need. You can then manage that branch instead. If you want to push up your changes, you should be able to back merge first. Git will know that you moved the files and do the merge successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is a "back merge" ? Can you offer an example?

Comment: a merge that goes "upstream" - from a higher order branch to a lower order one. Linus hates those. They tie in history from other branches that may have been merged already.

Comment: Could you please add some example about "back merge" in this situation?

Comment: Typically it's when you try and keep your feature branch current by merging in things from a mainline branch where everyone is merging their latest changes. This is bad because it ties your branch to others' work. If the product requires your branch but not one of the other ones already in the integration branch, it's not possible.

Comment: interesting idea, have anyone tried this? I am going to try soon, but still not sure that "back merge" can be clear and automated...

Comment: Did you try, dear @moudrick ? Are you with us still?! Considering what `Adam Dymitruk` stated regarding the hate, some may get... worried...

Comment: In my exact case, I ended up moving folders with history using `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` from [this gist from my starred list](https://gist.github.com/trongthanh/2779392),  as I did not actually need merging back.... To be honest, I don't remember more details on the case @Artfaith

Answer (score 6):

Save the submodule to the `submodules/` directory, and then create a symlink:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo submodules/repo
ln -s submodules/repo/subdir .
git add subdir
```

Result:

```
./
  submodules/
    repo/
      subdir/

  subdir  -->  ./submodules/repo/subdir
```

One benefit to this approach is that it can be reused with multiple subdirectories.