# How can I add a subdirectory of another git repository?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'd like to add a subfolder of a public github repository into a subfolder of my own repository.
I found a few solutions with git-sub-tree but there seems to be no way to pull changes from the original repository.

Is there a solution where I can merge changes from upstream?

Comment: Why not [`git subtree pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)? I think they will work for your use case.

Comment: nope you can only add a entire repo. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303496/how-to-change-a-git-submodule-to-point-to-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

If you need just one folder, you could clone the repo in another directory and then symlink the needed subdir.

```
$ pwd
> my-repo
$ cd ..
$ git clone <other-repo>
$ cd my-repo
$ ln -s ../other-repo/path/to/subdir ./directory/for/subdir/from/other/repo
```

Comment: Then my repository would only have a link to an unknown file. I want to track my changes against upstream.