# git submodule or ? - single file dependency

Tags: git, github, gentoo

I'm trying to use github to track my own portage overlay and wanted to be able to easily include & pull down changes from upstream file repos.

Thing is when I pull them down I will often only need a single file or a handful of files from the remote source repo that provided the original ebuild file I want to include in my repo.

What is the best/recommended way to track an upstream source repo but only 'in part', using git?

Example:
I want to include the content inside [this particular folder](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/tree/develop/packages/gentoo) of a git repo into my own git repo, without including the rest of the repo.

Edit:

It doesn't make sense to include the rest of the repo since an ebuild is just install instructions so I shouldn't be cluttering up my overlay with non ebuild files. And forking my own repo, deleting all their files and constantly only merging down part of it then making that a submodule of my overlay repo seems counter productive / over complex (not to say it may not be the preferred route, I'm still not sure I fully get how these git gurus think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Submodule to a subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121227/git-submodule-to-a-subfolder)

Comment: Has nothing changed since August 2009 ?

Comment: As far as I am aware: No. Please also check the second answer. It's from August 2012.